# Margin style could not work in Angular and Bootstrap

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am using inline style of margin in angular5 and bootstrap. My Template is defined as

```
@Component({
    selector: "dynamic-container-component",
    template: `
        <div 
            style="border: 1px solid; min-height: 10px; min-width: 10px; margin: 10px;" class="col">
        </div>
    `
})
export default class DynamicContainerComponent {
}
```

There multiple dynamic-container-component in a container.

```
@Component({
    selector: "container",
    template: `
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <dynamic-container-component></dynamic-container-component>
            <dynamic-container-component></dynamic-container-component>
          </div>
        </div>
    `
})
export default class Container{
}
```

It would produce a HTML which like below.

```
<div>
  <dynamic-container-component>
   <div style="border: 1px solid; min-height: 10px; min-width: 10px; margin: 10px;">
    </div>
  </dynamic-container-component>
  <dynamic-container-component>
   <div style="border: 1px solid; min-height: 10px; min-width: 10px; margin: 10px;">
    </div>
  </dynamic-container-component>
</div>
```

As a result, the margin style could not properly render in browser

Comment: you forgot to close `<div>` with `>`

Comment: Typo. Thanks and Updated.

Comment: but it not solve the issuse??

Comment: No. It cannot solve it as It is just typo.

Comment: No. But I would like to make the style work.

Comment: Sorry. I found that I have used with bootstrap. Example is 
written in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zsyate

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the .col class, witch has with 100% and collapsing margins. I suggest you set the following either in the parent component css, either in child css:

```
::ng-deep [class*="col"] {
   width:calc(100% - 20px) !important;  // twice the size of the 10px margin
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmgycy)