# Bootstrap 5 indents do not work in my Angular 15

Tags: html, bootstrap-5, angular15

Writing my project I can not apply bottstrap's paddings and margins for my inner elements, however the syntax and all the nesting rules are followed, as for me.  Here is the piece of markdown:
`<div class="col-8"> <div class="search-box row justify-content-between align-items-center"> <img src="assets/search-loupe-gray.svg" alt="loupe" class="col-1 loupe" /> <input type="search" placeholder="Placeholder" class="col-9 pe-8"/> <button mat-raised-button class="col col-2" style="height:100%"> <img src="assets/search-loupe-white.svg" alt="loupe" />Find</button> </div> </div>`
Bootstrap was installed via npm, and the link was added into index.html

Could not find any proper decisions to this issue. Once at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51007326/margin-style-could-not-work-in-angular-and-bootstrap) it was reccomended to override bootstrap's styles, but it is not an option

Comment: Sorry for bad styling in advance. This is my first question here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that the biggest value of spacings is 5. Here is an related [article](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding).
To tell more, you can add your own values by overriding bootstrap styles in any new .scss file stored inside the project and importing it in main "styles.scss" file